# Pass dictionary values a list in a function

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have  list of list. I want to pass the inner list in a function as list

```
('HNSPS150', ['19.41', 19.72, 18.64, 18.53, 20.36, 21.88, 21.84, 22.85, 23.06, 23.42, 23.69, 23.74, 24.27, 24.79, 25.68, 25.95, 26.16, 26.68, 26.97, 26.84, 26.95, 26.88, 27.02, 27.06, 27.13, 27.48, 27.86, 27.77, 28.51, 28.33, 28.58, 28.88, 29.28, 21.38, 21.36, 22.22, 22.67, 22.95, 23.41, 23.71, 23.73, 24.18, 24.23, 24.21, 24.76, 20.58, 18.96, 19.32, 19.95, 20.68, 21.03, 21.19, 21.68, 22.0, 23.39, 24.05, 23.44, 23.47, 23.71, 24.28, 24.64, 25.05, 25.84, 25.61, 25.55, 25.86, 26.74, 26.78, 28.1, 28.41, 28.19, 27.79, 28.54, 28.94, 28.98, 29.41, 29.67, 29.14, 29.7, 30.18, 30.33, 30.77, 31.1, 30.81, 31.18, 31.33, 31.54, 32.19, 32.61])
('HNSPS406', ['64.04', 64.7, 65.65, 66.01, 67.97, 68.54, 68.84, 68.05, 68.48, 70.99, 72.66, 70.51, 70.78, 71.79, 71.1, 71.91, 73.6, 73.65, 74.17, 74.3, 74.97, 74.78, 75.27, 76.18, 77.13, 77.11, 77.47, 78.19, 77.87, 78.32, 79.25, 81.45, 15.9, 15.69, 16.69, 17.61, 17.87, 18.51, 19.2, 17.89, 17.36, 20.11, 19.81, 20.64, 21.16, 21.19, 24.86, 26.68, 27.82, 28.48, 30.08, 29.71, 30.31, 31.6, 32.4, 33.33, 34.31, 35.44, 35.85, 36.58, 38.59, 38.79, 39.97, 40.42, 40.42, 40.95, 41.73, 44.13, 45.07, 46.13, 46.7, 50.55, 51.84, 51.83, 53.29, 53.78, 55.2, 28.88, 16.97, 17.8, 18.54, 22.0, 24.09, 23.99])
('CLL28DSQL4', ['64.60', 68.69, 70.03, 69.39, 70.04, 64.88, 66.14, 65.77, 66.02, 59.45, 67.53, 65.92, 68.74, 69.95, 66.3, 71.81, 70.16, 67.33, 68.43, 73.38, 66.71, 71.5, 69.99, 70.9, 70.41, 69.18, 71])
```

How can i access the list as a function parameter.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: dict lookup is with square brackets `my_dict['my_key']`

Comment: What you have posted is not a dictionary, its three tuples (one on each line), where the first element is a string and the second a list.  Please clarify exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @ Burhan Khalid i want to pass the list as a function argument. how can i do it?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid,I want to pass each list as a function argument. My function takes a list as a argument and provide percentile of the list

Comment: How? Just call the method with it. If the first line that you posted is called `y` (that is `y = ('HNSPS150', ['19.41', 19.72,....`), then `perc(y[1], .95)`.

Comment: print(k, percentile(v,.95)) is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Now explain what is `k` and `v`; and also how did the answer you accepted worked for you.

Comment: In my problem k is the string a d v is the list. But when i passed the list it gives me some error .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(LISTS))
```